# In flutter after every Text Form submission using sqflite the form should be cleared i.e the Fields should be empty after submission

Tags: sqflite, textformfield, flutter-form-builder

In flutter after every Text Form submission  using sqflite  the form should be cleared i.e the  Fields should be empty after submission .

I built an a flutter application  involving text form submission,  the form fields are showing me  even after submission.
I want o clear the form fileds i.e the answers or values after submission of the form uisng sqflite in flutter.

Comment: pls  somebody fix this issue

Comment: On the submit button, you can call `clear()` for each TextEditingController used. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController/clear.html

Comment: thank you please reply to my other queries also   Ok just suggest me How can I scroll even with a body: Builder( builder: (context) => Container( child: Column( as I have more list items before submit button etc and SUBMIT btton is not showing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64184955/i-want-to-place-a-custom-footer-image-from-the-assets-folder-into-my-flutter-app?noredirect=1#comment113593216_64184955

Comment: URGENT please attempt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64239403/please-guide-me-how-to-do-a-text-form-submission-and-store-in-firebase-using-flutter

Comment: First, stop mixing the issues by specifying them in comments. and secondly, I have already answered that question.

Comment: Ok thank you I will update you after trying the footer code.