# I want to place a custom footer image from the assets folder into my flutter application at the bottom of my application screen

Tags: image, flutter, footer

How to place a custom footer image from assets folder into my flutter application at the boottom of my application screen for ex my company logo image etc.

Comment: It is very Uregent  Can somebody  fix my issue.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/footer

Answer (score 1):

yes you can place your custom image as footer from your images or assets folder

as below:

using  in your .dart file in flutter

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset('images/myimage.png')),
          //color: Color(0xFF3A5A98),
        ],
      ),
```